# Context menu with ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using a ContextMenu in my xaml page under a ListBox to delete the ListBox Item.The problem I am facing is that when I long press the ListBoxItem the delete option appears and the item is deleted but when I try the next time the other item is not deleted.So can anyone tell me how on click of ContextMenu.Menuitem I can retrieve the list box Item details.Here's my code.

```
private void deleteitem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("username", out username);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("password", out password);
        ListBoxItem selecteditem = this.sniplist.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as MenuItem).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
        Item item = selecteditem.DataContext as Item;
        HttpWebRequest deleterequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response=deleterequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(deleteitem),deleterequest) as HttpWebResponse;
        //MessageBox.Show("Your item has been deleted");
    }
```

The deleteitem method

```
private void deleteitem(IAsyncResult ar)
{
//throw new NotImplementedException();
HttpWebRequest request=(HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
HttpWebResponse response=(HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);
if(response.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using(Stream respstream=response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respstream,
 System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                string parsestring = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine("Response data:" + parsestring);
            }
}
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        items.Remove(item1);
        this.sniplist.ItemsSource = items;
        MessageBox.Show("You item has been deleted");
        if (sniplist.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            txt1.Text = "Please click + to add more items into your account";
        }
    });


     }
   }
 }
```

Please help, I am stuck on this since two days.

Comment: are you getting the correct item in selectedItem variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by using the following

```
var item = ((MenuItem)sender).DataContext as ItemClass
```

ItemClass is the class that contains the binding details of different items,